# PHP Session Variable $user

Tags: php, session, variables

I were coding a website, And while I was making the login etc.
I started with this:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user']['id'], $_SESSION['user']['username'])) //etc ?>
```

I was wondering, Is it possible to make it into

```
<?php if(isset($user['id'], $user['username'])) //etc ?>
```

On any way?
Like, Will this work?
$user = `$_SESSION['user'];`

Comment: yes it will work. I use $_SESSION['user'] all the time and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. If you do `$user = $_SESSION['user'];` then you can use `$user` as shorthand for `$_SESSION['user']`

So `$_SESSION['user']['id']` could be shortened to `$user['id']`

Comment: Thank you mate, Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As you have it, you will need to set `$user = $_SESSION['user']` first, then you can use `$user['id']` as  shortcut to `$_SESSION['user']['id']`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['user']['id'], $_SESSION['user']['username'])) {
  $user = $_SESSION['user'];
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate, Just what I needed.

Comment: That appears correct. Line 30 shows that is `$_SESSION['user']` is set then create `$user = $_SESSION['user']`, perfect :)